# Python 3 __hash__() function throws TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I faced an issue with `__hash__()` function, while converting code from python 2 to 3. Basically, the same code in python 2 works normally while, in python 3 the TypeError has thrown.

What I want, is to inherit `__hash__()` from base class. Here's the classes structure:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, _id):
        self._id = _id

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._id)


class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, _id):
        Base.__init__(self, _id)
        self._id = _id

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._id == other._id

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)


a = A(5)

print(a.__hash__())
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ........
  File "C:/Users/.../test.py", line 39, in <module>
    print(a.__hash__())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: why do you call `a.__hash__()` ?

Comment: *"A class that overrides `__eq__()` and does not define `__hash__()` will have its `__hash__()` implicitly set to `None`. When the `__hash__()` method of a class is `None`, instances of the class will raise an appropriate `TypeError` when a program attempts to retrieve their hash value…"* — https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Comment: Yeah, but only in python 3.

Comment: In Python 2 this behaviour was rather expected to be implemented by the user, it became mandatory in Python 3: *"Classes which inherit a `__hash__()` method from a parent class but change the meaning of `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` such that the hash value returned is no longer appropriate [..] can explicitly flag themselves as being unhashable by setting `__hash__ = None` in the class definition."*